# Using QoS for HTTP

Tags: qos

By default what DSCP values are used when initiating HTTP traffic? If I wanted to match HTTP traffic to a DSCP value, what should it be?

Comment: There are no defaults for matching or marking HTTP traffic. Please specify your platforms and topology.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no default dscp value assigned do a HTTP connection by a web browser or web server when connections are initiated by either.

Answer (score 3):

Default QoS Markings are "Best Effort" (AKA "0")

Also, QoS needs to be honoured at each Hop, so it's mainly useless on the Internet (Most ISPs strip/remark to 0, or do nothing more with it)

Even if you managed to PAY for a better QoS handling, it would stop at your ISP's Peers borders.

Now, if you're talking for within your own lan, there are many ways to mark the traffic, depending on platform & topology, but each hop must be configured for it.  This means configuring each devices to classify/prioritize/process each type of traffic you have, the way you want it to be done.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier default DSCP values will be used and if HTTP is transported over provider boundary’s any DSCP will be reset. Unless you pay for any form of QOS will only work inside your network. (or by accident).